# How can I view all plots in Rstudio at once?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to scroll through all the plots I have created in RStuido. After a day of messing around with my data, I would like to see which of my plots I can use. So I would like to quickly scroll through thumbnails of my plots.

Waiting to click left in the existing plot viewer is taking a while as each one has to be redrawn before I can click left again. I would like to see them all at once and select one to inspect more closely. Is there a package or setting that I'm missing to be able to do this?

Comment: A couple of options to solve your problem: (1) make a layout and see all plots together in a panel; (2) make a PDF with all the plots, each in a page, for example.

Comment: This sounds like a feature request for RStudio - at the moment I don't think there's any way to control the RStudio graphics window from R code, for example there's no way to replicate the "previous" plot arrow button in R (plz correct me if I'm wrong). Try http://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: Gabriel, do either of the answers give you enough to work with? Curious if you found something else even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that provides some capability, though it is a little bit of a hack. The benefit is that it provides an easily-scanned array of thumbnails of your plotting history.

The package [`rmote`](https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote) provides the ability to look at plots remotely. That is, if I ssh to a remote host and don't want to try to do X-forwarding, I can forward a simple port and view all of my graphics on a web page. (Note: this works just fine locally with no ssh-ing required.)

```
devtools::install_github("cloudyr/rmote")

library(rmote)
start_rmote()
# To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop("140656622179224") or restart your R session
# Serving the directory /tmp/RtmpgOIU3c/rmote_server at http://127.0.0.1:4321
```

At this point, open a browser window to that URL, http://127.0.0.1:4321

Most of the rest of this answer is just demonstrating base graphics, `ggplot2`, and the not-working `gridExtra` ... plus the fix if you try that. The plotting code is immaterial, but the results that you see in your browser window are here:

[image: sample array of plots using <code>rmote</code>]

Base graphics require a little more work, using `plot_done()` when you are done "building" the plot. This is required (I think) because using base graphics typically requires several function calls (`plot` then things like `axis`, `lines`, more `points`, etc). Even if you want to do just a single-call plot and go with it, you still need to do `plot_done()`.

```
plot(mpg~disp, data=mtcars)
# serving graphics through rmote
# when finished with plot commands, call plot_done()
abline(a=10, b=1/10)
plot_done()
# making thumbnail
```

As soon as you run that last function, the web page is automatically updated with the full-size image and a list of thumbnails. I'll continue ...

`ggplot2` graphics work "as is", no need for `plot_done()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds)
qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 0.05)
qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram")
```

Unfortunately, I could not immediately get `grid.arrange` plots to work.

Normally, while you are working with `rmote`, there are no graphics devices:

```
dev.list()
# NULL
```

However, when I try to `grid.arrange` something:

```
library(gridExtra)
plot1 <- qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1)
plot2 <- qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 0.1)
plot3 <- qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 0.05)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol=3)
```

nothing is shown, but now we have a new device started:

```
dev.list()
# pdf
#   2
```

At this point, now normal plots don't work:

```
qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1)
# - not sending to rmote because another graphics device has been opened...
# - sending to the open graphics device instead...
# - to send to rmote, close all active graphics devices using graphics.off()
dev.list()
# pdf
#   2
graphics.off()
qplot(carat, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1)
```

and it updates again.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your setting, one option would be to organize your work into an R Markdown file.

That has an option to show all the charts inline, just set it under RStudio's `Tools -> Global Options ... -> R Markdown` menu. You will then have previews of all the charts in RStudio's editor and you can click on `Show in New Window` to investigate further:

[image]